# gridview: show link, but edit a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a gridview, and it has an author column. I want to display the author name as a hyperlink, so when the user clicks on it he gets redirected to the author page. But when the user wishes to edit the author for current product, he should see a dropdownlist. I am trying to implement it using a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="автор">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateURL='<%# "~/CMS/AuthorPage.aspx?a="+ Eval("AuthorID")%>' Text='<%#Eval("AuthorID")%>' />                                    
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnetdbConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM [Authors] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>                
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But how do I specify the selected value, and how do I store the selected value after edit?

Comment: I've tried using RowEditing event, but the dropdownlist isn't present in the cell's controls collection when this event occurs.

Comment: I've also tried  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" SelectedItemValue='<%# Bind("AuthorID") %>'>' /> , but ASP.NET says that there is no SelectedItemValue property in DropDownList, although there is one!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in `RowDataBound` event of `GridView` and then in `RowUpdating` event you can get the selected value

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "SomeID";
}
```

and get the selected value by

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)this.GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1");
    string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Waqas Raja! I could set the dropdownlist selected item using GridView1_RowDataBound, but I think that updating should be done differently. Besides, your second piece of code doesn't work.

Comment: The correct RowUpdating handler is:        protected void 
            DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)this.GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            e.NewValues.Add("AuthorID",  DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

Comment: @Bogdan0x400, thanks for your comments, yeah you are right there should be some different way to get selected value when updating. I corrected my code accordingly.